# Railo-Apache Config Issue: "example.com" points to /var/www while "example.com:8888" points to Railo

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, railo

As per my title, I was able to successfully install and run Railo and Apache on my VPS.

It runs Ubuntu 14.04.

My dillema is that I can't get example.com to point to my Railo root.

At present,

example.com points to /var/www

while

example.com:8888 points to my Railo root.

How do I make example.com point to Railo root?

I appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Here's what I appended to /opt/railo/tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Host name="example.com" appBase="webapps"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Context path="" docBase="/opt/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/gph" />
<Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
```

Heres my default conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

```
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and finally my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
    # hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #   /etc/apache2/
    #   |-- apache2.conf
    #   |   `--  ports.conf
    #   |-- mods-enabled
    #   |   |-- *.load
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   |-- conf-enabled
    #   |   `-- *.conf
    #   `-- sites-enabled
    #       `-- *.conf
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
    #   customized anytime.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
    #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
    #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
    #   respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    #
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
    # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

    #
    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #
    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    #
    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #
    KeepAliveTimeout 5


    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
    # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on
    Include ports.conf


    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #   AllowOverride None
    #   Require all granted
    #</Directory>




    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>


    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive.
    #
    # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
    # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
    # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
    # requests.
    #
    # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
    # Use mod_remoteip instead.
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
    # see README.Debian for details.

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
    Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        <Proxy *>
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfchart)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        # optional mappings
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flex2gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flex2gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/messagebroker/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/messagebroker/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flashservices/gateway(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flashservices/gateway$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/openamf/gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/openamf/gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    </IfModule>


    PerlRequire /opt/railo/tomcat_connectors/mod_cfml/mod_cfml.pm
    PerlHeaderParserHandler mod_cfml
    PerlSetVar LogHeaders false
    PerlSetVar LogHandlers false
    PerlSetVar CFMLHandlers ".cfm .cfc .cfml"
```

Comment: Posting your config would be a good start..

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited my question to include the files. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It's probably getting intercepted by your `default.conf` since it has a stanza for *:80, any traffic to the IP on port 80 will get served by that. You'll need to set up a stanza for default.com:80, and ensure that it redirects to railio.

Comment: Fixed by uninstalling apache and reinstalling railo and set it to default to port 80. :) Turns out the built in Tomcat server was good enough. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Fix:

Turns out I didn't need Apache in the first place.

I basically rebuilt my VPS image so that I can still use the same DNS settings.

Then I installed railo using the official linux installer.

When prompted for the Tomcat Web Server Port: I chose port 80.

www.example.com now points to Railo root.

However, I am reminded that this uses Tomcat 7. There are security issues to consider.